# How to use supplyAsync of CompletableFuture to run the same method with multiple inputs each time?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I have the following code where I create a supplier and use the completableFuture's supplyAsync method to invoke another method after async execution.

```
public void runParallelFunctions(MyInput myInput) {
    Supplier<Map<String, String>> taskSupplier = () -> {
        try {
            return invokeLambda("input1");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return new HashMap<>();
    };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(taskSupplier::get, executorService)
                         .thenAccept(this::printResultsFromParallelInvocations);
    }
    System.out.println("Doing other work....");
}
```

Below is the method I call after the execution completes.

```
private void printResultsFromParallelInvocations(Map<String, String> result) {
        result.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));
}
```

In the above code, how can I call the method `invokeLambda` passing multiple arguments like "input1", "input2" etc.? I can generate the inputs through a loop, but how can I use some sort of a list with the supplier so that I can call the entire list for supplyAsync method? I cannot use runAsync method because I have a return value that I need to call `printResultsFromParallelInvocations` with. I'm new to futures and async callbacks and would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't understand the question. *..the supplier so that I can call the entire list for supplyAsync method*: Can you elaborate this part?

Comment: Why do you insist on creating a single supplier for doing different things? There is, by the way, no sense in using `taskSupplier::get` instead of just `taskSupplier`. With the former, you are creating a new supplier in each iteration that does nothing but calling the `get` method of the already existing supplier. Use something like `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { String input = "input" + i; CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> invokeLambda(input), executorService) .thenAccept(this::printResultsFromParallelInvocations); }`, but you should change the misleading method name `invokeLambda`.

Comment: @Holger thanks so much for the response. I didn't realize I was getting a new supplier each time with supplier.get, my bad. Could you post this as an answer? I'll accept that. I'll also rename the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not create a single `Supplier<Map<String, String>>` and expect it to behave differently for the five evaluations. It would require external mutable state to make it detectable that an evaluation is the n’th evaluation which at the same time contradicts the idea of performing five *concurrent* evaluations which have no order.

Simply create five different suppliers, e.g.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String input = "input" + i;
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> invokeLambda(input), executorService)
        .thenAccept(this::printResultsFromParallelInvocations);
}
```

In each loop iteration, the lambda expression `() -> invokeLambda(input)` captures the current value of `input` and creates an appropriate `Supplier` instance.

Side notes:

- Don’t name methods after technical aspects like `invokeLambda` but rather try to express their *purpose*.
- the `taskSupplier::get` in your original code was an unnecessary method reference as it produced a `Supplier` invoking the method on an object that was already a `Supplier`. So `taskSupplier` could have been passed to `supplyAsync` directly if getting the same behavior for every evaluation was intended.

Comment: Holger : Great passing param to Supplier inline. What if i needed to create Future as follows: CompletableFuture future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(mySupplier);  how to pass parameter now if my supplier looks like Supplier<String>  mySupplier = () -> return // what to return if supplies doesn’t accept any parameters by design?

Comment: @Striker suppliers do not support parameters in the narrow sense in general. In the example, it captures the value of `input` from the surrounding context here (that’s why the variable must be effectively final, which is the reason why the lambda expression can’t use `i` directly). The syntactic form doesn’t matter. You can write, e.g. `Supplier<String> mySupplier = () -> input;` or `Supplier<String> mySupplier = () -> someMethod(input);`, directly before the `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier) …` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new Supplier on the fly inside the loop.

```
public static Supplier<Map<String, String>> supplierFunc(Object... args) {
    return () -> {
        try {
            return invokeLambda(args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return new HashMap<>();
    };
}

public void runParallelFunctions(Object myInput) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplierFunc("input1", "input2"), executorService)
                .thenAccept(this::printResultsFromParallelInvocations);
    }
    System.out.println("Doing other work....");
}
```